# View block not accepting contextual filter argument

Tags: views

I have a Basic Page node and on it I have View block that displays another content type.

The View takes a Contextual Filter `Taxonomy term: Term ID` with the following settings:

When the filter value is NOT available:
`Provide default value` - `Raw value from URL`;`Path component: 2`;`Use path alias`

When the filter value IS available or a default is provided:
`Specify validation criteria` - `Validator: Taxonomy Term`;`Filter value type: Term name converted to Term ID`

So if my node has a path of `/foo` and my term name is `bar` then if I browse to `/foo/bar` I'd want to see my Basic Page node with my View filtered by the term `bar`.

When I test this in the preview widget the view works as expected; only returning the data that is associated with the term `bar`. When I actually browse to `/foo/bar` I receive a Page Not Found error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the node page do you have term id in url?

Comment: Yes. example.com/foo would be the node, bar being the term name. When I test foo/bar in the preview widget; it works. On the node view with bar also in the url; I receive the 404 error.

Comment: Is this a taxonomy term page, or is this a node that has a term reference field? If so, you shouldn't be using Raw Value from URL, you should use the Taxonomy Terms on Node relationship. What is your end goal for this View block?

Comment: The page is a node. The view is displayed as a block on that node page. The view is displaying another content type. My goal is to be able to filter the view with an argument in the path alias URL (not internal URL.)

Comment: Right, but all you're really wanting to do is show content that shares the same term, right? So if the node page is associated with term A, you want to show other content that is also associated with term A, correct?

Comment: No the node doesn't have any associated terms (none that are relevant here anyway.) The node is just a landing page; the view displays teaser content that link to their full-content selves.

Comment: Is there any reason that you have not created view display as page instead of block

Comment: Yes, this is a landing page that has both copy in the body field plus call out fields (node references) that display user selected content in the side bar. Several other sections have been implemented this way and it makes sense to stay consistent.